# Inability to input text in my forms input boxes in react.js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am unable to type within my label boxes, this has got me incredibly confused as I'm trying to make a simple username/password registration form that logs the data into a database, however this isn't really possible without having the ability to input data. Wondering if I can get some assistance.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { username, password} = user;

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user", user);
   
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow">
          <h2 className="text-center m-4">Register User</h2>

          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="Username" className="form-label">
                Username
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your username"
                name="Username"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="Password" className="form-label">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your Password"
                name="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
            
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I looked at the code but i’m just incredibly confused, it looks fine to me

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't have the correct names in your input.

Replace `Password` by `password` and `Username` by `username`.
It has to be the same as in your state.